# SignalR issue calling server method from client

Tags: signalr

I have an mvc application and have implemented SignarlR.  The purpose of using SignalR is to allow my back-end controller to send updates to the front end client to inform it of it's progress.  The method on the controller could potentially be a long running process.  I have registered 4 different events on the client that can be called from the controller.  All that is working just fine.

So I determined that I wanted to give my user the ability to cancel the long running process if they wanted to.  So I created another method in the Hub that the client could call and that method would set a flag that the back end could check to see if the process was cancelled.

For some reason, I cannot get the server call from the client to work.  It will NOT call the server method.  I have code snippets of each piece below.

**HUB Class**

```
public class ScanInventoryHub : Hub
{
    private string _connectionId = string.Empty;
    private bool _scanCancelled = false;

    public bool ScanCancelled
    {
        get
        {
            return _scanCancelled;
        }
    }

    public ScanInventoryHub(string connectionId)
    {
        _connectionId = connectionId;
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ScanInventoryHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.Client(_connectionId).addNewMessage(message);
    }

    public void SetProgressCount (int count)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ScanInventoryHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.Client(_connectionId).setStatusBar(count);
    }

    public void IncrementItemProgressBar()
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ScanInventoryHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.Client(_connectionId).incrementItemProgressBar();
    }

    public void IncrementProgressBar(int percentage)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ScanInventoryHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.Client(_connectionId).incrementProgressBar(percentage);
    }

    public void CancelScan()
    {
        _scanCancelled = true;
        Debug.WriteLine("Cancel Scan");
    }
}
```

**Client Side Script**

```
    messageHubProxy = $.connection.scanInventoryHub;

    messageHubProxy.client.addNewMessage = function (message) {
        //html stuff is happening here
    };

    messageHubProxy.client.setStatusBar = function (count) {
        //html stuff is happening here
    }

    messageHubProxy.client.incrementItemProgressBar = function () {
        //html stuff is happening here
    }

    messageHubProxy.client.incrementProgressBar = function (percentage) {
        //html stuff is happening here
    }

    $.connection.hub.logging = true;

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        messageHubId = $.connection.hub.id;

        $.ajax({
            url: Utility.GetBaseUrl() + 'Controller/Action',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                connectionId: messageHubId,
                .....
            },
        });
    });
```

**Cancel Button Click Event Handler**

```
    CancelScan: function (e) {
        messageHubProxy.server.cancelScan();
    }
```

SignalR Log of one of my local runs is below

```
[14:53:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'scaninventoryhub'.

[14:53:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?
clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22scaninventoryhub%22%7D%5D'.

[14:53:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22scaninventoryhub%22%7D%5D'.

[14:53:45 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport starting.

[14:53:45 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://localhost:5325/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=2.1&connectionToken=UtyYkw5kgPhCQH40iaWKHE2SE4SWGq2q3A0EJQ%2FopAsCPr61jfIBD301cBT3iwxZX9%2Fkk4wuh%2BPljBciCFNYtubMUMnlU1MPF2a88tFRKaDQbebT3OrHuTVLEoY4qLzY&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22scaninventoryhub%22%7D%5D&tid=6'.
SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 302, Redirect

[14:53:46 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Websocket closed.

[14:53:46 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Closing the Websocket.

[14:53:46 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.

[14:53:46 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting.

[14:53:46 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: This browser doesn't support SSE.

[14:53:46 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.

[14:53:46 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport starting.

[14:53:46 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Binding to iframe's load event.

[14:53:47 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Iframe transport started.

[14:53:47 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport connected. Initiating start request.

[14:53:48 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.

[14:53:48 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000

[14:53:49 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'setStatusBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:53:49 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:53:49 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addNewMessage' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:53:49 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addNewMessage' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:53:51 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport timed out when trying to connect.

[14:53:55 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:53:55 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addNewMessage' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:53:56 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoking scaninventoryhub.CancelScan

[14:53:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:53:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addNewMessage' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:02 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:02 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addNewMessage' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:05 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:05 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addNewMessage' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:08 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:08 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addNewMessage' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:10 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:12 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:14 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:16 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:18 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:19 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:19 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addNewMessage' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:26 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:29 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:32 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addNewMessage' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:38 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:42 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:42 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addNewMessage' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:43 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'incrementItemProgressBar' on hub 'ScanInventoryHub'.

[14:54:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: scaninventoryhub.CancelScan failed to execute. Error: Error: Send failed.

[14:54:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection.

[14:54:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Stopping forever frame.

[14:54:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true.

[14:54:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Stopping the monitoring of the keep alive.
```

Comment: So nobody knows how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Since nobody can seem to answer my question, is there another group that I should post this question to?